# Override openAboutPanel: NSDictionary key/value length limit?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

There seems to be an arbitrary (~238 characters, it seems) limit to the length of any value in the NSDictionary used in this method provided by Apple to programmatically implement an "About Panel" in an OS X Cocoa app. Is there a way to override this limit? Thanks...

```
- (IBAction)openAboutPanel:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *options;
    NSImage *img;

    img = [NSImage imageNamed: @"Picture 1"];
    options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                @"1.1", @"Version",
                @"Super App", @"ApplicationName",
                img, @"ApplicationIcon",
                @"Copyright 2005-2006, My Great Company", @"Copyright",
                @"Super App v1.1", @"ApplicationVersion",
                nil];

    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] orderFrontStandardAboutPanelWithOptions:options];
}
```

Comment: Design your own panel and display that instead.

Comment: If I knew how to, or had any interest in doing so, don't you think I would? Down-vote for stating the useless obvious.

Comment: No need to be defensive. You want to take advantage of a convenience, but it doesn't suit you. That's when you implement your own approach.

Comment: Fair enough. Any suggestion as to where I could find some novice-level resources to get me started on such an endeavor?

Comment: Here are two URLs to get you started: http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2002/06/14/cocoa.html?page=2 and http://lifeasclay.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/cocoa-programming-for-mac-os-x-chapter-12-challenge/. The first one's kinda old and bare-bones, but the second one has more details.